# Is there a fast way to create a bool matrix from another matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy

i would like to know if there is a faster way, not O(n^2), to create a bool matrix out of an integer nxn-matrix.

Example:

given is the matrix:

```
matrix_int = [[-5,-8,6],[4,6,-9],[7,8,9]]
```

after transformation i want this:

```
matrix_bool = [[False,False,True],[True,True,False],[True,True,True]]
```

so all negative values should be `False` and all positive values should be `True`.

The brute force way is O(n^2) and this is too slow for me, too you have any ideas how to make this faster?

Comment: how can you make this faster when you need to see all values and decide each one is negative or positive?

Comment: Is this really a list of lists, or already a numpy array?  Your use of "matrix" is ambiguous.  The operation will be O(n**2) for n rows, but O(n) tor total number of elements.  Creating an array from a list takes time, which may cancel out any time savings from a faster array test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matrix_int = [[-5,-8,6],[4,6,-9],[7,8,9]]

matrix_int = np.array(matrix_int)
bool_mat = matrix_int > 0
```

result:

```
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
matrix_int = [[-5,-8,6],[4,6,-9],[7,8,9]]
matrix_bool = [[num > 0 for num in row] for row in matrix_int]

# [[False, False, True], [True, True, False], [True, True, True]]
```